# pass message from the parent window to child user control wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a window that is hosting a user control. I wish to pass (raise) events in the parent window that should reach the user control.
How do I define events in the parent window that the child user control can also receive.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall the steps should be:

1. Define a delegate in your parent window
2. Define an event in your parent window
3. Lets say in your window Loaded event attach the usercontrol to the
   event, eg -

   this.MyEvent += new
       this.MyDelegate(this.UserControl1.SomeMethod);

   Take note that
   SomeMethod must match the MyDelegate definition.
4. Raise the event in your parent window per application logic.

For examples of how to define delegates/events then google is your friend ;) Also don't forget to unregister your usercontrol from the event, when it's no longer required (when the window closes).